# How to use Hibernate UserTypes in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to use/register a Hibernate UserType in a JPA project, where no annotations are used but the persistence mapping is done in a JPA orm.xml file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution I can see is to write mappings for the classes with properties of custom type using `.hbm.xml` syntax and then add them to `persistence.xml` with `<mapping-file>` - Hibernate supports it, but I'm not sure how it would play with other classes mapped in `orm.xml`.